# Why is almost every program complaining about my locale?

Tags: arch-linux, locale, glibc

I'm using Arch Linux, and I've followed the directions on the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) about setting my locale.

Nearly every program that runs complains about the locale - even `locale`. It looks like this:

```
% locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en-US
LC_TIME=en-US
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY=en-US
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT=en-US
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

or:

```
% perl
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en-US",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en-US",
    LC_MONETARY = "en-US",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en-US",
    LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C")
```

Something slightly confusing is that the `/etc/locale.gen` has several examples; all the UTF-8 lines have "something.UTF-8", and running `locale-gen` shows `en_US.UTF-8... done` while it's running, but `locale -a`, which is supposed to show you the available locales shows `en_US.utf8`. I've tried various combinations of both formats in `/etc/locale-gen` and `LOCALE=` in `/etc/rc.conf`, but nothing has fixed the problem.

Additional information:

```
% locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
```

Bruce Ediger's suggestion of setting `LANG=C` and `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` worked (in fact, setting `LC_ALL` fixed it, setting `LANG` didn't matter), but I'd like to know what's happening. According to [SUS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html), LC_ALL will override all the other LC_* variables if it is set and not null. In my system, it is set, but it is null, so it should be ignored, and other values should be used instead. That's not what's happening, it seems that applications are calling `setlocale` with `LC_ALL`, getting a `NULL` back, and generating an error, even when other calls to `setlocale` return a good string.

Here is the top of an `ltrace` of `locale` (scroll right to see function return values)

```
% ltrace locale
(0, 0, 0, -1, 0x7f5c1ae44510)                                                                      = 0x7f5c1ae47140
__libc_start_main(0x401d70, 1, 0x7fff7c8cfbf8, 0x404610, 0x4046a0 <unfinished ...>
setlocale(0, "")                                                                                   = "en_US.UTF-8"
setlocale(5, "")                                                                                   = "en_US.UTF-8"
textdomain("libc")                                                                                 = "libc"
argp_parse(0x607280, 1, 0x7fff7c8cfbf8, 0, 0x7fff7c8cfad4)                                         = 0
setlocale(6, "")                                                                                   = NULL
dcgettext(0, 0x405aa8, 5, 0, 0)                                                                    = 0x405aa8
error(0, 2, 0x405aa8, 1, 0locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: can you share the output of `locale -a`?

Comment: I was going to point that you should use `.utf8` in `LOCALE` and `LC_*`, but apparently `.UTF-8` works here too... As for en-US: does it appear (without `.utf8`) in `locale -a`?

Comment: Do `export LANG=C` and `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and see what happens. My Arch linux laptop has `LOCALE="en_US.UTF-8"` in /etc/rc.conf, and I can't figure out where my laptop sets LANG=C .

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/locale.conf`?  It looks like you accidentally wrote `LANG=en-US` (with hyphen) instead of `LANG=en_US` (with underscore).

Comment: And the contents of `/etc/locale.gen` would be useful too.

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve the problem, can you post the output of `strace -e file`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're missing a file which would be used to default the locale in the absence of `$LANG` or `$LC_ALL` (or *all* of the more specific `$LC_whatever`) being set.

On older glibc, it's `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`.
Because GNU/Linux is chaotic, you should use strace
to determine which files are expected in the particular
versions in use on your machine:

```
strace -e file locale
execve("/usr/bin/locale", ["locale"], [/* 36 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
```

----------------------Comments added 1 day later:

`ltrace -S` should be okay, since it shows syscalls.

Otherwise, "ltrace" is not very helpful (i.e. it's counterproductive versus `strace`), because it only shows the uppermost calls.  Those are obvious (`setlocale(3)`), whereas the real problem happens within `libc`.

It sounds like you have the *raw* locale data installed,
since `en_US.UTF-8` works.

If so, then something like this should fix your problem,
setting a system-wide default:

```
localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: `sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8` works on Raspbian 2018-11-13 Lite.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after setting up `/etc/locale.conf` just today (relating to the recent changes to `/etc/rc.conf`. In my case, it turned out that the locales were not installed.

Check `/etc/locale.gen`. All the locales which your environment variables reference must be activated (i.e. not commented out) in there. After having made your changes, run `sudo locale-gen` to install the selected locales.

Answer (score 3):

Following this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#Setting_the_locale) solves my problem :

```
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
# or change to en_US.UTF-8 depends on your locale-gen
```

it generates a file `/etc/locale.conf` that fixes this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems recently, all unicode file names were incorrectly displayed, when I accidentally removed the 'LOCALE=en_US.utf8' in `/etc/rc.conf`. So I checked the boot script:

```
if [[ $DAEMON_LOCALE != [nN][oO] ]]; then
    export LANG=${LOCALE:-C}
    if [[ -r /etc/locale.conf ]]; then
        parse_envfile /etc/locale.conf "${localevars[@]}"
    fi
else
    export LANG=C
fi
```

Simple solution is check both `DAEMON_LOCALE` and `LOCALE` in `/etc/rc.conf`, make sure the first one wasn't `no` and the second one wasn't empty.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe one of your settings is invalid? These are my locale settings for reference; they don't cause any errors (KUbuntu 12.04):

```
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```